# JavaScript hoisting for multiple declarations of the same variable

Tags: javascript, hoisting

I was trying to understand JavaScript hoisting and from what I have understood, memory space is set aside for all the variable declarations before the execution of the code.

I would like to understand how the interpreter works through hoisting in case of multiple declarations for the same variable. Consider the following code:

```
 console.log(a);

 //first declaration
 function a() {
     console.log('hello');
 }

 //second declaration
 var a = 2;
```

The output is the function declaration:

```
function a() {
    console.log('hello');
}
```

So, I am assuming the first declaration the interpreter encounters is the one which is stored in memory. However, changing the order of declarations to:

```
console.log(a);

//first declaration
 var a = 2;

//second declaration
function a() {
    console.log('hello');
}
```

results in the same output! The interpreter ignores the first declaration and stores the second declaration in memory. Why is this happening? Shouldn't the output in the second case be `undefined`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will be read by the interpreter like below,

```
 function a() {
     console.log('hello');
 }
 var a;
 console.log(a);
 a = 2;
```

so while executing the above code, `a` will be referring the function initially and after that `var a;` line will be executed, since `a` is undefined there, an assigned value will not be set with `undefined` by means of a variable declaration. Hence that line got ignored and printing the `primitive` value of the function reference.

A simple example for your better understanding would be,

```
function x(){  };
var x;
console.log(x); //function x(){  }
```

Comment: so subsequent multiple declarations are ignored if they are trying to set an already assigned value to undefined?

Comment: @TarunDugar Yeah exactly. The already assigned values will not be replaced with undefined by means of a variable declaration.